# How can I transform UIButton to circle?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to animate a `UIButton` to circular shape, when user clicks on it. But I am getting the top part of the `UIView` as flat when I try to do that. Pasting my code below.

```
private enum SignInButtonState {
        case clicked
        case normal
    }


private var currentSignInButtonState: SignInButtonState = .normal
private func updateSignInButton(to state: SignInButtonState) {
        switch state {
        case .clicked:
            signinButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
            self.currentSignInButtonState = .clicked
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.signinButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.signinButton.frame.height/self.signinButton.frame.width, y: 1)
                self.signinButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.signinButton.frame.height/2
                
            }
            
        case .normal:
            signinButton.setTitle("Sign In", for: .normal)
            self.currentSignInButtonState = .normal
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.signinButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                self.signinButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
                
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried adding

```
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Neither helped. Adding the image of the UIButton when tried to change shape to circle(button in yellow)

[image: Gif of what is happening]

[image: Current output of UIButton being a circle]

Comment: can you show us `currentSignInButtonState`

Comment: `cornerRadius` is animatable property, you don't need transform.

Comment: @MohmmadS It is added to code, now

Comment: @vpoltave I used transform to bring the width down to match the height. To get the 1:1 aspect ratio

Comment: Can you attach an image of your result please?

Comment: Doesn't this gives you something like 0.1 or similar result? `self.signinButton.frame.height/self.signinButton.frame.width` can you print values or user breakpoint to check what you actually assign?

Comment: @vpoltave Added the image

Comment: @SidharthJDev check updated answer and if u need more help I would be happy to help :) gif was added to show result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update, I found out about your width, the issue is in transform as it makes the `.cornerRadius` misbehave, trying another approach would solve it

- I can see your width == to view width

So we need to create another width constraint with a constant value
and create `IBOutlets` in code for both, and change the priority of each when clicked and changing the values while changing corner radius, check below

```
@IBOutlet weak var secondWidthConstant: NSLayoutConstraint! // this is the constant one
@IBOutlet weak var widthOfBtn: NSLayoutConstraint! // this is the one that has == to super.view

  private func updateSignInButton(to state: SignInButtonState) {
    switch state {
    case .clicked:
        signinButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        self.currentSignInButtonState = .normal
        widthOfBtn.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750) // this one is the constraint that is == to the width of the view
        secondWidthConstant.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000) // this is the constant value constraint
        secondWidthConstant.constant = self.signinButton.frame.height // change the constant after the priorty is set to higher than the == one
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.signinButton.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.signinButton.layer.cornerRadius = (self.signinButton.frame.height / 2)
        }) { (_) in
        }
    case .normal:
        widthOfBtn.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000) //switch back priorty
        secondWidthConstant.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750) //switch back priorty
        signinButton.setTitle("Sign In", for: .normal)
        self.currentSignInButtonState = .clicked
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.signinButton.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.signinButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. What is the difference between the solution and the question I posted?

Comment: you'r flag was mistaken also I don't know where you call this function I assumed from didTap on button

Comment: @SidharthJDev try it out it works for me fine also even if you call it also from didLoad after clicking it also works fine.  your mistake was setting it to clicked in your case clicked and normal when your case is normal

Comment: @SidharthJDev check video your code had a bug in the flag setting for status tats what different from your code

Comment: Did not work yet, because my button starts off at full width of screen(with margins).

Comment: try to call it from did load then when clicked

Comment: but make sure to switch the flag to .normal as an initial state

Comment: work as fine here, there might be some missing parts you're not mentioning

Comment: I have added a gif of what is happening. I don't think I have missed out on anything

Comment: OKay  i see the problem, what's your button height

Comment: It is set with Autolayout (48 pts)

Comment: @SidharthJDev kindly check updated code and snippet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220550/discussion-between-sidharth-j-dev-and-mohmmad-s).

Comment: @SidharthJDev no problem all I needed was a bit more details :) please upvote for effort :D thanks